# How to speedup integration of interpolated function with logarithmized data?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, interpolation, logarithmic-scale

Consider some dataset corresponding to the grid `x1, x2, function[x1,x2]`:

```
function[x1_, x2_] = Exp[-x2/25]*Cos[20*x1]^2*Sin[x1];
dataset = 
  Flatten[Table[{x1, x2, function[x1, x2]}, {x1, 
     Table[10^
      x, {x, -5., Log10[1/20. Pi/2], (Log10[1/20. Pi/2] + 5.)/
       20}]}, {x2, 
     Table[10^
      x, {x, Log10[5.3], Log10[200.], (Log10[200.] - Log10[5.3])/
       20}]}], {1, 2}];
{x1min, x1max} = MinMax[dataset[[All, 1]]]
{x2min, x2max} = MinMax[dataset[[All, 2]]]
```

I interpolate it in two ways:

```
int1[x1_, x2_] = 10^(Interpolation[{Log10[#[[1]]], Log10[#[[2]]], Log10[#[[3]] + 10^-90]}&/@dataset, InterpolationOrder -> 1][Log10[x1], Log10[x2]]);
int2[x1_, x2_] = Interpolation[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}&/@dataset, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x1, x2];
```

The integration of the `int1` is much slower than `int2`:

```
testfunction[x1_, x2_] = Sqrt[(1 - Cos[x1])]*Exp[5/x2];
NIntegrate[int1[x1, x2], {x1, x1min, x1max}, {x2, x2min, x2max}, 
  Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"] // AbsoluteTiming
NIntegrate[int2[x1, x2], {x1, x1min, x1max}, {x2, x2min, x2max}, 
  Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"] // AbsoluteTiming
NIntegrate[
  int1[x1, x2]*testfunction[x1, x2], {x1, x1min, x1max}, {x2, x2min, 
   x2max}, Method -> 
   "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"] // AbsoluteTiming
NIntegrate[
  int2[x1, x2]*testfunction[x1, x2], {x1, x1min, x1max}, {x2, x2min, 
   x2max}, Method -> 
   "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.960714, 0.0146339}
>
> {0.0011156, 0.0189933}
>
> {1.01974, 0.000414336}
>
> {0.0718938, 0.000659965}

On the other hand, `int1` has better behavior in case if `function` changes fast between the neighboring values of `x1`, `x2` in the grid.

Switching to "AdaptiveMonteCarlo" integration method somehow improves the situation, but non-negligible difference in timing (up to a few times) remains (it's funny that it slows down much the integration of `int2` without `testfunction`).

Could you please tell me how to speed up the integration with `int1`?

Comment: What does `int1` have to do with `int2` ?

Comment: Of course `int1` is slower: In addition to evaluating an interpolation function, it has also to evaluate `10^...` and `Log10`.

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve here?

Comment: This question seems ill-defined, because you're relying on *Mathematica* to give you an interpolation of a function, and it could be computing the two interpolations totally differently. One might have $1000$ times as many points as the other one. That would be my first guess as to why one is slow vs. fast. I think you need to provide more context for the question to be meaningful to others. What real data are you given to work with, and what are your options for processing it? I assume that you're finding one option is a lot slower than the other, but otherwise preferable.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : I would like to get the accurate interpolation in the domain where the distribution function decreases fastly (large `x1` and `x2`), keeping also good performance.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann : excuse me, I do not understand the question. The functions should give the same results if working with them (e.g., integrating), just the way of interpolation is different.

Comment: @Myridium : I will work with interpolation of data that quickly drops (exponentially or via the power law) in some domain. Given the lack of grid points, I need to logarithmize the data when interpolating. But this feature slows down all calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you try to use the substitution formula:

$$
\int_a^b \int_c^d f( \varphi(x),\psi(y)) \, \varphi'(x) \, \psi'(y) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
=
\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(a)} \int_{\psi(c)}^{\psi(d)} f(u,v) \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}v.
$$

So you could apply this to $\varphi(t) = \psi(t) = \log_{10}(t)$ or $\varphi(t) = \psi(t) = 10^{t}$. (I don't know at the moment which direction would be suitable for you.)

If $\varphi'(x) \neq 0$ and $\psi'(y) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $y \in [c,d]$, then you may define

$$
    g(u,v) := f(u,v) \, \varphi'(\varphi^{-1}(u)) \, \psi'(\psi^{-1}(v)),
$$
which leads to the following identity:
$$
\int_a^b \int_c^d g( \varphi(x),\psi(y)) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
=
\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(a)} \int_{\psi(c)}^{\psi(d)} g(u,v) \, \frac{1}{\varphi'(\varphi^{-1}(u))} \, \frac{1}{\psi'(\psi^{-1}(v)))}  \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}v.
$$

The point is to apply this to the following function $g$:

```
ip = Interpolation[Transpose[{Log10[x], Log10[y], Log10[z + 10^-90]}],
InterpolationOrder -> 1];
g[x1_, x2_] := 10^ip[x1, x2];
```

`Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` should allow for fast integration of the integral on the right. And if I understand correctly, it is the integral on the left that you want to compute in the end.

Comment: Glückwunsch zu den 100k!

Comment: Hey, danke! War 'ne Menge Arbeit... =)